# WebSockets how to handle 2 or more same user windows

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

For example one user Has entered to my site and my websocket server accepted the connection, then the user opens a new window, how should I handle that new connection, should I deny a user or treat him as a new user?, also it will take more loops to update the information in both windows, any hints?

I just can't understand this moment, please any explanation on how it should be most logical solution?

Comment: That really depends on your application and what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat it like the same user with a different connection.

You can identify the user by a cookie value, or a value in the local storage that is sent after connection. If you refresh or open a new tab, it is still considered the same connection.

You can identify the connection by a random id in the url or session storage. If you refresh the tab, it will be considered the same connection and it will reattach.

If you are familiar with .NET, I have a small project about a [Terminal Server via WebSocket](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-Terminal-Server)  that uses this approach.

In this example the same user can open independent tabs, and in those he is still considered the same user.